# Scrapy spider successfully extracts data but does not write to .csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, extract

I have created a Scrapy spider to extract data from a website and save it to a .csv file. The spider runs without any errors and I can see the extracted data when I print it to the console. However, when I try to write the data to a .csv file, only the column names ('title', 'views', 'date') are saved and none of the extracted data is written to the file. Can someone please help me understand what could be causing this issue? Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import csv

# Open the Chrome browser and go to the ... website
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('here's the site I'm getting info from')

# Wait for 1 second for the website to load
time.sleep(1)

# Scroll the webpage to wait for the appearance of a button
scroll_pause_time = 1
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")
j = 1
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{j});".format(screen_height=screen_height, j=j))
    j += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary')) > 0:
        break

# Click on the button
btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary')
btn.click()

# Wait for 2 seconds for the webpage to load completely
time.sleep(2)

# Scroll the webpage to the end
scroll_pause_time = 1
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")
i = 1
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    if driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight <= window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;"):
        break
    if time.time() - start_time >= 10:
        break

# Create a Scrapy response object from the Selenium page
response = HtmlResponse(url=driver.current_url, body=driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')

# Create a .csv file and define a writing object
with open('site_org.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'views', 'date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    # Write header row to file
    writer.writeheader()

    # Add data to file
    for anime in response.css('.anime_row'):
        title = anime.css('.anime_title a::text').get()
        views = anime.css('.anime_views::text').get()
        date = anime.css('.anime_date::text').get()

        writer.writerow({'title': title, 'views': views, 'date': date})


# Create a class for the the_site spider
class SiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'site_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://the_site/']

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('site_org.csv', mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['title', 'views', 'date']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            # Add data to file
            for anime in response.css('.anime_row'):
                title = anime.css('.anime_title a::text').get()
                views = anime.css('.anime_views::text').get()
                date = anime.css('.anime_date::text').get()

                writer.writerow({'title': title, 'views': views, 'date': date})

# Start the spider to begin parsing
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SiteSpider)
process.start()

# Print message indicating the results have been saved to file
print('Results saved to site.csv')
```

If anyone has any suggestions or insights on why the extracted data is not being written to the .csv file, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without a [mre] at first glance it appears that you can simply remove your `SiteSpider` and the lines that create and start the `CrawlerProcess` completely since it doesn't seem to actually be doing anything for you.  That is, if the url you are using in `driver.get` is the same url that you put in `start_urls`.  Although I am not certain this will solve your issue, in its current state that whole section is useless.

Comment: Check Feeds config in setting.py